# Can I find who did an HTTP request?

Tags: malware

I am mentioned that my server did an HTTP download some days ago, and it may be a virus. I have the request's source IP/port, the destination IP/port, the protocol, time, length, and method.

Maybe my server is hacked, but I want to find which user and which program did the HTTP request. Is it possible? Do Linux records all outgoing HTTP requests? If not, is it possible for me to find with the information above?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using httpd server then you have http log it may helps you with your request (there is extra [mod](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dumpio.html) for Apache mod_dumpio may provide better feedback) , and I suggest you to run this command on demand to know better what is currently requesting http on your server

```
# tcpdump filter for HTTP GET 
sudo tcpdump -s 0 -A 'tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2):4] = 0x47455420'

# tcpdump filter for HTTP POST 
sudo tcpdump -s 0 -A 'tcp dst port 80 and (tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2):4] = 0x504f5354)'

# tcpdump for specific client
tcpdump -vvvnn port 80 and host ip_addr_of_client -i any
```

Comment: Sorry if my question is not clear, I mean if I can find a request done someday last week, not now. I know it sounds ridiculous but maybe there's some chance.

Comment: Hi, What is the application server you are using for your site? maybe it recorded http request through a specific log file

Comment: Do you mean `nginx`? Since it's an outgoing request, I didn't think my HTTP server will have the log.

Comment: httpd server is a powerful application it has hundreds of mods you can refer to their official website for more info regarding http log https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dumpio.html